# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object laravel 8

Tags: laravel

Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: D:\Courses\Buildwithangga\BWAFD\nomads-app\resources\views\includes\admin\navbar.blade.php)

I'm using Laravel 8, but i did not install jetstream, i install laravel/ui (Is that make any problem??)

And when i add {{ Auth::user()->name }} in navbar.blade.php, it will run error

This is my navbar.blade.php

```
<!-- Sidebar Toggle (Topbar) -->
<button id="sidebarToggleTop" class="btn btn-link d-md-none rounded-circle mr-3">
  <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</button>

<!-- Topbar Navbar -->
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="mr-2 d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small">
        {{ Auth::user()->name }}
      </span>
      <img class="img-profile rounded-circle" src="https://source.unsplash.com/QAB-WJcbgJk/60x60">
    </a>
    <!-- Dropdown - User Information -->
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logoutModal">
        <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
        Logout
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Thankyou :)

Comment: try to use auth directives & check if user is logged in , Auth would return null if not logged in, you can try to check the value of `Auth::check()` [see here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#determining-if-the-current-user-is-authenticated) or use `@auth`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because when a user is not logged in, Auth::user() will be null and you cannot access a property name on null.

You can tackle this in

```
@auth
<span class="mr-2 d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small">
    {{ Auth::user()->name }}
</span>
@endauth

//OR

<span class="mr-2 d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small">
    {{ optional(Auth::user())->name }}
</span>
```

Out of the above two options using @auth is better because in the second option an empty span will still be included in the page. Where as with @auth whatever is in between @auth and @endauth will only be included on the page if user is logged in.

Comment: Thanks, it's works now

Have a good day :)

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Pls remember to mark the answer as accepted/upvote for the benefit of subsequent visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Multi-Level authentication? I passed for same issue because I wasn't seeing to Auth::guard correctly.